# SQL LEFT JOIN Not returning the correct DATA

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, right-join

Im tryoing to build a SQL join table, but it is not returning the correct data that i want. 
So i have a sliders table with structure like below.
[image: sliders Table structure]

So the table has a foreign key that referes to an item. Items or sliders have a same column called: published, that tells if a sliders/items is or is't published.

I'm trying to build a query that returns all sliders that are published AND items where they belonge are published, Joined with the sliders where item_id is nll.

So according to the image above the query should return only 3 rows with id (2-3-4), because item with id 34 (item_id=34) on table items is not published therefore  it shouldnt be on the returned value. The query that i have build so far is this:

```
SELECT *
FROM sliders
LEFT JOIN items ON sliders.item_id = items.id
WHERE sliders.published =1 AND items.published =1
```

But the query returns only 2 rows. rows with id 2 and 3 which correspond to item with id 23, 28.

The returned result is as follow:

[image: returned Result]

So it returned 2 rows instead of 3, the row missing is the row with id 3, where item_id=null.

I have been trying all day to figure this out but it seems i am stuck here...

Any help would be very appreciated..

Comment: can you post either sql statements to set up sample data or a sqlfiddle?

Comment: Probably just need to move `AND items.published =1` from the WHERE clause into the ON clause of the join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a LEFT JOIN and there isn't a match, the right hand table (`items`) will have `NULL` as the values of its columns. You therefore can't have `items.published = 1` in your WHERE clause and expect those rows to show up because `NULL` doesn't equal `1`.

Assuming I've not misunderstood the question, you'll need to change that to `AND (items.published IS NULL OR items.published = 1)` - you could probably also get away with just doing `AND items.published <> 0`. That essentially checks that the items are published *if they exist*.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Final query that returns the correct Data.

```
SELECT *
 FROM sliders
  LEFT JOIN items 
    ON sliders.item_id = items.id
WHERE sliders.published =1
 AND (
   items.published IS NULL
   OR items.published =1
)
```